# grant create index on specific table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle and I want to create an index to a specific table belongs to another user so how I grant the privilege to do so without using the requete

```
grant create any index
```

Comment: Can't you ask the owner to create the index?

Comment: No, I had to create from another user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grant index on [tablename] to [user]
```

What privileges the table owner him/herself must have in order to be allowed to grant create index on a table to another user will depend on your version of Oracle; check the documentation.

Comment: that didn'r work, I had the error message missing or invalide privilege.I use oracle 10g

Comment: My mistake, I had the wrong syntax. Fixed now - deleted the word "create". Please let me know if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a index to a table in another schema first you need to grant the system privilege to the user you want use to create de index.

> To create an index in another schema, you must have
>   the CREATE ANY INDEX system privilege.

More reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm

Here the SQL:

```
/*No tested*/
Grant create any index to user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure in table owner schema

```
create or replace 
procedure create_index(col_list varchar2, index_name varchar2) as
begin
execute immediate 'create index ' || index_name || ' on ' || 'PUT_TABLENAME_HERE'|| '(' || col_list || ')';
end;

GRANT EXECUTE ON table_owner.create_index TO user;
```

Call

```
begin
table_owner.create_index('ID','IDX1');
end;
```

I think it should work.